# UPLOAD IMAGE IN A FOLDER WITH PHP

Tags: php, image, upload

I've try this code to upload an image with php , but not work and i don't know why...

this is my form

```
<form action="conn/inserimento.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file"  name="immagine" /><br>
    <div id="container-button">
        <input type = "submit" value="Pubblica" name ="submit" class="btn-send">
    </div>
</form>
```

this is my script in php

```
$path="uploads/";
$target_file = $path . basename($_FILES["immagine"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["immagine"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $target_file . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add:

```
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that code is taken from https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp
if you would scroll a bit down to "Complete Upload File PHP Script" you would notice `move_uploaded_file(...)` which is moving your file from temp to destination.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this links for upload file.

```
visit https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp
visit https://cloudinary.com/blog/file_upload_with_php
visit https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_uploading.htm
```

hope this will help you.